# Trying to insert a background image via TikZ results in extra white-space around the corners

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

I am trying to insert a background image in my beamer template as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,c,aspectratio=169,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}


\setbeamertemplate{background}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
     \node {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

    \section{Introduction}

    \begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

this results in

[image]

as you can see, due to some sort of bounding box around the inserted image, there is a space from the north-west corner of the image in `(x-y)`. However, I would like to position the image in the starting at the north-west corner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set `inner sep=0pt`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,c,aspectratio=169,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}


\setbeamertemplate{background}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
     \node[inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

    \section{Introduction}

    \begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the hint ;).